# Android Calculator using WebView

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-webview, calculator

Hey everybody I have a problem.
I'm pretty much new to Android Development and a current assignment for a Uni course is to design a simple Calculator. The tutor told us that we could either implement the calculator ourselves with two stacks that keep track of numbers and operators and then do everything manually

OR

use the WebView Object with JavaScript to solve whatever the user types in :P This sounds better so I googled around a little bit to find a basis to trying to understand.
I found this tutorial:

http://www.androiddom.com/2011/04/creating-android-calculator-tutorial.html

I will first explain my problem and then paste the code: Basically The ButtonClickListener isn't working! I press a button, nothing happens, the WebView Object stays blank like nothing is going on. When I change the line in the tutorial where they set the JavaScript to "true" to something I found in the official Android documentary from Google and run the application it crashes as soon as I push a button. So the buttons are sending broadcasts but my code isn't doing anything with it. Now here the code:

```
package edu.calpoly.android.lab1;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.webkit.WebView; 
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    private WebView mWebView;   
    private StringBuilder mMathString;  
    private ButtonClickListener mClickListener;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
    @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         // Create the math string      
         mMathString = new StringBuilder();

         // Enable javascript for the view      
         mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

         // Set the listener for all the buttons        
         mClickListener = new ButtonClickListener();        
         int idList[] = { R.id.button0, R.id.button1, R.id.button2,
                R.id.button3, R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6,
                R.id.button7, R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.buttonLeftParen,
                R.id.buttonRightParen, R.id.buttonPlus, R.id.buttonPlus,
                R.id.buttonMinus, R.id.buttonDivide, R.id.buttonTimes,
                R.id.buttonDecimal, R.id.buttonBackspace, R.id.buttonClear };

        for (int id : idList){ 
            View v = findViewById(id); 
            v.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);       
        }

    }

    private void updateWebView() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("<html><body>");
        builder.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.write('");
        builder.append(mMathString.toString());
        builder.append("');"); 
        builder.append("document.write('<br />=' + eval(\"");
        builder.append(mMathString.toString()); 
        builder.append("\"));</script>"); 
        builder.append("</body></html>");

        mWebView.loadData(builder.toString(), "application/xhtml", "UTF-8");    
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {           
            switch (v.getId()) { 
                case R.id.buttonBackspace:
                    if (mMathString.length() > 0)
                        mMathString.deleteCharAt(mMathString.length() - 1);
                    break;          
                case R.id.buttonClear:
                    if (mMathString.length() > 0)
                        mMathString.delete(0, mMathString.length());
                    break;          
                default:
                    mMathString.append(((Button) v).getText());             
            }

            updateWebView();        
        }    
    } 
}
```

AND THE XML LAYOUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLeftParen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="(" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRightParen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=")" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonBackspace"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="B" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="C" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTimes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="*" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDecimal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="." >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonEquals"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="=" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

^ The layout is pretty boring, just wanted to post it for the sake of it. Thank you in advance already!

Comment: Have you tried using the `Log` class to see if your implementation of `OnClickListener` actually works?

Comment: It worked fine for me!! What error messages do you see in logcat when app crashes?

Comment: Using the exact code I posted I get this error message:

11-14 09:54:13.237: E/ThrottleService(150): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Hmm…other than that. What Android Version did you use? I'm building for 4.1 ...too high? Might that cause some issues because things changed over time?